# Unable to load .app file into iOS simulator using Appium 1.5.2 on Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4

Tags: java, ios, macos, cordova, appium-ios

I am attempting to load a .app file into the ios Simulator to test a cordova hybrid app on an Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4. 
Using java + testng

```
Appium version : 1.5.2
Xcode version : 7.3
ios simulator used : iPhone 6 (9.3)
java version : 1.8.0_91    

The desired capabilities are :
DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities(); 
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.IOS);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"iPhone Simulator");
File appdir = new File("src");
File app = new File(appdir,"/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app");
```

I tried the hybrid app and it did not work . I than tried a native ios TestApp to check if it is due to it being a hybrid app. But that also failed
In both cases  i am getting following error from the Appium server stating :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred    while processing the command. 
Original error: Could not extract Info.plist from  application: Plist file 
   doesn  exist:'/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/AndroidTest/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads      
TestApp.app/Info.plist' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace   information)
```

I can load the same app TestApp from command line into the ios simulator

```
xcrun simctl install booted /Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app
```

So it appears to be an issue in the Appium server .

The appium log is

```
        [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.2 (REV 6fdcab5abcffbbb0a3a734e1db7d7afe6cac753a)
        [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
        [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator"}}
        [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone Simulator...
        [Appium] Creating new IosDriver session
        [Appium] Capabilities:
        [Appium]   app: '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app'
        [Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
        [Appium]   deviceName: 'iPhone Simulator'
        [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 698c8531-e612-4e4c-9aaa-ee4534d25553
        [debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.
        [BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app'
        [debug] [iOS] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
        [debug] [iOS] Cleaned up instruments socket /var/folders/6h/8kb9nvyn695fh0p4jgy8yzp00000gp/T/instruments_sock
        [debug] [iOS] Setting Xcode version
        [debug] [iOS] Xcode version set to 7.3
        [debug] [iOS] Setting iOS SDK Version
        [debug] [iOS] iOS SDK Version set to 9.3
        [debug] [iOS] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
        [debug] [Instruments] Getting list of devices instruments supports
        [debug] [Instruments] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instrument
        [debug] [Instruments] Available devices: Apple TV 1080p (9.2) [A5FE6CCA-3A7B-4220-9AD3-DC0BCFB22CD8] (Simulator),iPad 2 (9.3) [EF4E9EC0-E008-4A26-A0B5-81E7E0C0ED16] (Simulator),iPad Air (9.3) [C3E8A5C6-8C4B-46A3-93FD-F9697A969001] (Simulator),iPad Air 2 (9.3) [A7AACD06-1D71-49B2-9283-B607462E944C] (Simulator),iPad Pro (9.3) [9503510E-C3A2-4E11-8E00-2038D79F1A56] (Simulator),iPad Retina (9.3) [1A4A82A7-1B3C-4E32-9C67-C4E857F28B7D] (Simulator),iPhone 4s (9.3) [FE282F1C-7AAB-453E-84F7-B5D9E7CC9685] (Simulator),iPhone 5 (9.3) [249EED76-F108-4266-B465-19A5128272E1] (Simulator),iPhone 5s (9.3) [4AB901CC-8A39-4B96-94A4-72DD2EBD6591] (Simulator),iPhone 6 (9.3) [78C5497B-EB06-46A9-87CE-331F2B99E10C] (Simulator),iPhone 6 Plus (9.3) [E357E070-2DB5-422B-B1A3-5583BE587212] (Simulator),iPhone 6s (9.3) [494FBF78-2165-4671-AE78-987D4D9E8DF3] (Simulator),iPhone 6s (9.3) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.2) [E152E587-A30D-41B9-AF40-916E44E18907] (Simulator),iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) [95FC414D-98B8-4786-A47E-18F550456164] (Simulator),iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.2) [16668096-3A92-4881-9A58-5F25AD517155] (Simulator)
        [iOSSim] Retrieving device name string for Xcode version 7.3
        [debug] [iOSSim] Getting device string from options: {"deviceName":"iPhone Simulator","platformVersion":"9.3","forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false}
        [debug] [iOSSim] Fixing device. Changed from 'iPhone Simulator' to 'iPhone 6 (9.3) ['
        [debug] [iOSSim] Final device string is 'iPhone 6 (9.3) ['
        [debug] [iOS] iOS sim UDID is 78C5497B-EB06-46A9-87CE-331F2B99E10C
        [iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 7.3
        [debug] [iOS] No language specified. Using default strings
        [debug] [iOS] Strings file not found. Looking in 'en.lproj' directory
        [iOS] Could not file localizable strings file 'Localizable.strings'!
        [debug] [ios-app-utils] Getting bundle ID from app
        [Support] Error: Plist file doesn't exist: '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app/Info.plist'
        at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
        at Object.parsePlistFile$ (lib/plist.js:22:11)
        at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
        at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
        at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
        [Error: Plist file doesn't exist: '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app/Info.plist']
        [ios-app-utils] Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Plist file doesn't exist: '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app/Info.plist'
        at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
        at extractPlist$ (lib/extract.js:14:9)
        at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
        at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
        at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
        [Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Plist file doesn't exist: '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app/Info.plist']
        [iOS] Could not set the bundleId from app.
        [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not extract Info.plist from application: Plist file doesn't exist: '/Users/spoonitydev/workspace/Android-Test/src/Users/spoonitydev/Downloads/TestApp.app/Info.plist'
        at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
        at extractPlist$ (lib/extract.js:14:9)
        at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
        at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
        at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
        at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Has anyone encountered this issue of appium not being able to extract the Info.plist file even though it is present in the .app file and that xcrun can install it successfully ?

Comment: Have you got solution over it?

Comment: Made some changes to the capabilities for ios and that worked

Comment: What changes did you make?